# Unique row number per date with partition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data containing product codes and dates that data was updated, I'd like to number the rows per product code, so that I can select only the most recent update.

I tried the following code:

```
SELECT
ChangedDateTime,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductCode, ChangedDateTime ORDER BY ChangedDateTime DESC) change_id,
ProductCode
FROM `dataset.table`
```

But it returns:

```
Row ChangedDateTime change_id   ProductCode
1   2019-06-06 08:08:01.510 UTC 1   A11
2   2019-06-05 08:08:01.510 UTC 2   A11
3   2019-06-04 16:02:13.087 UTC 1   A11
4   2019-06-05 08:08:01.510 UTC 1   A110
5   2019-06-04 16:02:13.087 UTC 1   A110
6   2019-06-04 14:36:54.930 UTC 1   A110
```

When I would expect to see:L

```
Row ChangedDateTime change_id   ProductCode
1   2019-06-06 08:08:01.510 UTC 1   A11
2   2019-06-05 08:08:01.510 UTC 3   A11
3   2019-06-04 16:02:13.087 UTC 2   A11
4   2019-06-05 08:08:01.510 UTC 1   A110
5   2019-06-04 16:02:13.087 UTC 2   A110
6   2019-06-04 14:36:54.930 UTC 2   A110
```

How can I adjust my code to get this to function correctly and what is my current partition doing to number these incorrectly?

Comment: The values for your `change_id` don't make sense (at least to me).  Can you explain the logic you want for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the partition by `date`:

```
SELECT
ChangedDateTime,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductCode ORDER BY ChangedDateTime DESC) change_id,
ProductCode
FROM `dataset.table`
```